# Why Python built in "all" function returns True for empty iterables?

Tags: python

I know it has a good reason, but I want to know what reason?

```
>>> print all([])
True
```

If all() is intended to check if every item on iterable evaluates to "True", and we know empty lists are evaluated to False

```
>>> bool([])
False
```

So why the all() returns True for empty lists?

< edit >

I already read the docs, and I know the implementation

```
 def all(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True
```

But the question is why not?

```
def all(iterable):
    if not iterable:
        return False
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True
```

There is a logic on this? if you have a list of done-tasks

```
today_todo_status = [task.status for task in my_todo if task.date == today]
can_i_go_home = all(today_todo_status)
```

Ok, on the above **hypothetical** example it really makes sense, if I have no tasks, so I can go home.

But there are other cases and I dont think all() was made for todo lists.. LOL

< /edit >

Comment: As pointed out, all states are simultaneously true and false for nothing, and a null set contains nothing.  What really makes sense for your example is not `all(today_todo_tasks)`, but `any(map(lambda task: task.status != DONE, today_todo_tasks))`.

Comment: The C# Linq All extension method behaves the same way.

Comment: I think the duplicate as mentioned by @MarkMikofski has much clearer explanation to why question.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is expressed as "For all X in S, X is true". If S is empty, there are no X. However, the truth statement remains True, because for all X, X was true... there just aren't any X!

Here is a explanation [using logic](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/474051-any-all-empty-list).

> Consider two sets A and B where A+B is the union of the two sets.
>
> If any(A+B) = True -> any(A) or any(B) = True but we cannot assert
> either any(A)=True or any(B)=True.
>
> If any(A+B) = False -> any(A) = False and any(B) = False.
>
> If all(A+B) = True -> all(A)=True and all(B)=True
>
> if all(A+B) = False -> all(A)=False or all(B)=False but we cannot assert either all(A)=False or all(B)=False.
>
> Now instead of B, let's add the empty set Ø to A. We want to come up
> logic such that adding the empty set does not change the values of
> all() or any(), since A+Ø=A.
>
> any(A+Ø) = any(A) or any(Ø)
>
> any(Ø) must be False, so that if any(A) is True, any(A+Ø) is True, and
> if any(A) is False, any(A+Ø) is False.
>
> all(A+Ø) = all(A) and all(Ø)
>
> if all(A) is True, all(A+Ø) is True. Therefore, all(Ø) is True.

Comment: As this answer (correctly) implies, the all() function is intended to mimic the universal quantifier in mathematics, which is defined to be true when applied to the empty set.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth for a discussion of why this is the case, and why it feels wrong to many (including the OP).

Comment: vacuous truth leads to bugs;
`if all(nuclear_sub.has_been_destroyed for nuclear_sub in fleet):  launch_doomsday_device() `
Now what happens on the day we decommission the last sub??

Answer (score 10):

[`all()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all) (documented to "*Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (**or if the iterable is empty**).*") is equivalent to the following:

```
def all(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True
```

Since there are no elements, it will skip the loop and return `True`.

Comment: This is just circular logic that begs the question.  'It was defined this way because this is the way it was defined' is not really an answer...

Comment: I saw that on the docs.. but it does not answer the question. 
Why not check if the **iterable** is False and return it?

Comment: @sr2222 It shows the logic behind how `all()` operates. By showing that the method returns `True` unless there is a `False` element in it, we can understand why it returns `True` for an empty list.

Comment: @rochacbruno Why would you check if it was `False` first? A list with all `True` elements can be empty; a set of 0 elements is still a set that contains no `False` elements.

Comment: The question is not how does it operate, but why was it made to operate that way.  @Interrobang actually provides an explanation.  It is as if rochacbruno asked, "why does the Earth rotate around the sun," you answered, "because an orbit is defined as a body moving around another body," and Interrobang answered, "gravity."

Answer (score 2):

This comes from the mathematical logic.

"everything is true of the elements of the empty set" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set)

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth

Answer (score 2):

Suppose `all([])` is `False`.

Then, for all non empty list `A`, `all(A + [])` should be also `False` as

```py
all(A + []) = all(A) and all([])
            = all(A) and False
            = False
```

Since `A + [] = A`, we know

```
all(A + []) = all(A) for any non empty list A
```

But, `all(A)` could be `True` (e.g., `A = [True]`)

Hence,

> for all non empty list `A`, `all(A + [])` should be also `False`

This contradicts. As a result, the first assumption is wrong and

`all([])` is `True`

Answer (score 1):

Because *all* elements are True. When there are no elements, you can say that 'all elements are ... anything'

Answer (score 0):

ELI5 version.

Take a list of numbers

```
L = [1,2,3,4,6]

all([isintance(l, int) for l in L])
```

`all` is defined in such a way that, the only way to make it `False` is by supplying `at least` one non-integer.

Similarly `any` is defined in a way that, to make it `True` all you need is `at-least` one positive integer.

Since `all()` is the complement of `any()` one must be `True` and other must be `False`

Answer (score 0):

When testing for a condition, we want the first element to always be added to the list.  For example, if we only want to add numbers to a list if they are less than the smallest number or greater than the largest number we can do this:

```
def addToList(less,num):
    if less:
        if any( num >= savedNum for savedNum in numbers):
            print('{} is not less'.format(num))
            return
    elif any( num <= savedNum for savedNum in numbers):
        print('{} is not greater'.format(num))
        return

    numbers.append(num)


numbers = []
doLess = True
doMore = False
addToList(doLess,5) #numbers is empty, but will be added
addToList(doLess,2)
addToList(doLess,7)
addToList(doMore,15)
addToList(doMore,9)
print(numbers)
```

Output:

```
7 is not less [5, 2]
9 is not greater [5, 2, 15]
[5, 2, 15]
```