# `all` builtin function on empty iterable always True

Tags: python

Python builtin function `all` docs state the following:

> all(iterable) -> bool
>
> Return True if bool(x) is True for all values x in the iterable.
> If the iterable is empty, return True.

Is there a case when `all([]) == True` is actually useful?

eg.:

```
a = []

if all(a) and a:
    print 'OK'
```

Could be replaced with just `if all(a): print 'OK'`.

Now I have to declare my variables with `['']` and then ensure that at least one item is always in the list, which I find quite annoying.

I know there's another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979683/why-python-built-in-all-function-returns-true-for-empty-iterables), which explains why such choice was made, but I just wonder when it is actually useful?

Comment: You can `if a and all(a)`, the reason it returns True is you have nothing to iterate over, all is deigned to check the content of an iterable not to check for empty iterable.

Comment: So to put it differently, I should use `all` only when I'm certain, that my iterable is not empty. Well that's imposed by the docs... They wanted to be mathematically correct, I get it... And still I think  `all([]) == False` would be a lot more useful. So what is the use case when `all([]) == True` is actually handy?

Comment: It is a design choice for the reasons in the question you linked to,  there is also a big difference between a list where one or more elements are falsey values or you have no elements at all,  a simple if catches the latter and often you would want to know when you actually have nothing at all in your iterable as opposed to what all is designed to catch.