# how can i improve my code on euler problem 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, primes

I have started to learn python and after doing some basic I started to do euler problem. I was able to do 7 but the compilation takes a long time. Can someone help me?

This is the only code I have written

```
def prime(n):
    count = 0
    if n <= 1:
        print("Number is neither prime nor composite")
    if n == 2:
        print("Number is prime")
    if n > 2:
        for i in range(2, n//2 + 1):
            if n % i == 0:
                count += 1
            else:
                count += 0
    if count == 0:
        return True
    else: 
        return False


b = 10001
a = []
i = 2
while len(a) < b:
    if prime(i):
        a.append(i)
        i += 1
    else:
        i += 1
print(a[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to find all the factors of a number. Once you find a factor, the number is obviously not a prime, and you can return `False` immediately.

EDIT:
As Federico Domeniconi mentioned in the comments, there's also no need to iterate up to half of `n`. Iterating up to its square root would suffice:

```
if n > 2:
    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False

    # No factors found, n is a prime:
    return True
```

Comment: You can improve by using `range(2, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1)`.

Comment: @FedericoDomeniconi True 'dat

Comment: should't be `int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1`?

Comment: @FedericoDomeniconi arg, yes (edited). The second argument of a `range` is exclusive.

Comment: I tried using square root but i was getting wrong answer

Comment: @GauravSharma care to elaborate?

Comment: and skip the even numbers, after first checking if it's divisible by 2. Cuts the work by 1/2 for primes.

Answer (score 0):

And if you really want to boil this type of solution down:

```
def is_prime(n):
    factors = range(2, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1)
    return (n > 1 and all(n % f for f in factors))
```

One unexpected trivia item that I might have known once and forgotten. Why does the function return `True` for `n = 2`?

```
factors # range(2, 1 + 1)
        # range(2, 2)
        # Which is an empty range.
        # Or in more concrete form: an empty list.

n > 1   # True
all([]) # Hmmmmm?
        #
        # Are all of the items in an empty collection true?
        #
        # If every tree falls in the forest at once, but no one hears them,
        # does it make a sonic boom?
        #
        # Contrary to Billy Preston -- and microeconomists world wide --
        # can you really get something from nothing?
        #
        # Python says YES. I'm sure smart mathematics do too, but
        # I would be curious to hear the reasoning.
```

I guess StackOverflow has the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979683) to my question. And logicians have a [name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) for this situation: "a **vacuous truth** is a statement that asserts that all members of the empty set have a certain property."

Comment: that's because `forall x in S. P(x) === forall x in S. not( not( P(x) )) === not( exists x in S. not(P(x)) )` and there certainly isn't such element in S for which `not(P(x))` is the case, -- as there simply are no elements in S -- and so we end up with `not( False )` i.e. `True`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working through the Project Euler problems then it is a good idea to have your own [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).  That can calculate prime number *very* quickly, much faster than trial factorization, the method you are currently using.  You will find it useful for a number of their problems.

The solution to Euler 7 then becomes:

1. Estimate the size of the 10,001st prime number, using the [Prime Number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem).
2. Run the Sieve of Eratosthenes up to the limit from step 1, and a little beyond for safety.
3. Count through the output from your sieve to find the 10,001st prime.