# Why any() and all() return different values on empty iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x

From the python docs:

> ```
> all()
> ```
>
> Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty).
>
> ```
> any()
> ```
>
> Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return False.

What's the logic behind making `all([])` True? I would think (perhaps naively) that if you had an empty set or list or whatever, doing `all()` on it should evaluate to False, since none of the items are True.

Comment: "since none of the items are True". But none of them are false either :)

Comment: It has been discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979683/why-python-built-in-all-function-returns-true-for-empty-iterables  any([]) can be explained in similar fashion based on that.

Comment: Saying "every item is true" is equivalent to saying "there are no items that are not true". That applies to `[]`

Comment: `any` starts `False`, and iterates until it hits a `True`, then quits.  `all` starts `True` and iterates until it hits a `False`, then quits.  You can confirm this by `timeit` one lists of various lengths.