# Why for loop can work with an empty set in all()?

Tags: python

Python newbie here. So I'm reading [Whirlwind Tour of Python](https://jakevdp.github.io/WhirlwindTourOfPython/12-generators.html)

and there is an example:

```
def gen_primes(N):
    """Generate primes up to N"""
    primes = set()
    for n in range(2, N):
        if all(n % p > 0 for p in primes):
            primes.add(n)
            yield n

print(*gen_primes(100))
```

for this line: `if all(n%p>0 for p in primes)`, I suppose primes is still empty, why for loop still working?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) documentation:

> Return `True` if all elements of the iterable are true (or ***if the iterable is empty***).

In your case the underlying generator yields an empty value, it's like `all([])` or `all(set())` thus an empty iterable passed into `all()` builtin.

You're most likely looking for this instead, so you first check if it's not empty, then check for all of the elements against some condition.

```py
if primes and all(...):
```

Though as mentioned in the comments, in your particular code, that would cause `if False`, so you need to rewrite the implementation a bit or split the conditions into two IFs.

---

If you're into C, you might find [the underlying `all()` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ed524b4569b1e4a166886c880018418d46284378/Python/bltinmodule.c#L322) interesting, especially [this part](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ed524b4569b1e4a166886c880018418d46284378/Python/bltinmodule.c#L337) which I think simply exits the loop and thus causes [`return True`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ed524b4569b1e4a166886c880018418d46284378/Python/bltinmodule.c#L356).

Kind of like this:

```py
for _ in iterable:
    # here check for false and return
# aaand the iterable is empty, so meh
# no loop and falls directly to the last return
return True
```

Comment: They're most likely *not* looking for `if primes and all(...):`. That would cause `gen_primes` to never yield anything.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica yes, in that context, no in the context of preventing `all()` returning `True` on an empty iterable.

Comment: This is an interesting thing side about `all()` _(and `any()`)_. Maybe [here is more info on the reasoning for that, which seems rooted in boolean logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11979709/2889970). These exact characteristics of those builtins did prove useful at times.

Comment: I really hate the *"or if the iterable is empty"* part. Completely unnecessary and just irritating.

Comment: You hate the definition, or the fact that they make it clear? There are sound mathematical reasons for defining `all([]) == True`. The key is to recognize that `all(xs)` returns `True` not when every element of `xs` is true, but when *no* element of `xs` is false.

Comment: Yeaaah, it's a silly thing if you look at it this way because it's unexpected if you don't read the docs (and most people, especially beginners don't) and will hit hard when you least expect it even if you read it. :)

Comment: @chepner I meant that the doc says that. Makes it seem like that needs to be said, as if "all" doesn't mean what it means.

Comment: I would add that as Pythonistas, when in doubt, we are acustomed to empty iterables being falsy! That may not help initial expectations here ;) Anyways good that the docs are explicit on that. I think @chepner explained it very well in the most succinct way.

Comment: @chepner Also: *"all(xs) returns True not when every element of xs is true"* - Actually that's exactly what it does.

Comment: Perhaps "mathematical/logical `all()`" and "expected `all()`" should be two separate functions, but as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68786548/5994041) the result might not make sense afterwards unless the "expected `all()`" raises an exception when the iterable is empty, which **then** might even comply with the Zen of Python. But once unwound that way it's just easier to implement it by one self or just learn how it works.

Comment: @KellyBundy That's pretty stilted English, though. The doc writers are stuck trying to write something that's mathematically precise without sounding artificial. I would go with something like "Returns true unless there is a false element in the iterable". I suspect, though, they really wanted to work the word "all" into the definition to make it more obvious why the function is named `all`.

Comment: (And I realize that my definition makes it sound like `all(xs)` is *usually* or expected true, except for some corner exceptions, instead of something that has a roughly equal chance of returning true or false.)

Comment: (Scratch that: given a uniform distribution of sequences of Boolean values, `all(xs)` is far more likely to return `False` for an arbitrary sequence `xs`.)

Comment: @chepner Well they could for example write "Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (*which includes the case* that the iterable is empty)". But the "or" thingy makes it sound like if that wasn't said, it wouldn't return True if the iterable is empty.

Comment: "x if y or if z" is pretty standard English for "x if y and x if z" (which is similar to the reason for legions of beginning programmers thinking that `x and y == z` is the same as `x == z and y == z`.

Comment: @chepner Not sure what you're trying to say with that. Using that example of yours, I'm saying that it should be "x if y". And that needlessly adding something else makes it sound like that *needs* to be added, which is wrong, irritating, and misleading.

Comment: I'm saying that you seem to be finding something wrong or misleading about a perfectly ordinary English sentence.

Comment: @chepner The sentence isn't wrong but it's misleading. What's wrong, as I said, is the implied *need* of the addition. It does *not* need to be added. Let me simply go a bit further, maybe you'll see my point then. Imagine they said `Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty or if it has exactly three elements and all of them are true or if the iterable is the list [1,2]).`. Wouldn't you think that that's weird? That that's unnecessary? That this addition makes it sound like these cases otherwise wouldn't result in True? Which is wrong?

Comment: People without a mathematical background are far more likely to think that `all([])` would return `False` because there are no elements in [] that are true, therefore it's *not* true that all the elements are true. *That* is the target audience for the parenthetical.

Comment: @chepner Well I'm not saying they shouldn't educate such people, just that they should do it properly. Like with my *"which includes the case that the iterable is empty"*. That would educate such people without the issue. The way they're doing it is irritating for people who do know, and *miseducating* people who don't. Their way *reinforces* the misbelief that "all" is normally false when there are none.

Comment: There's nothing *improper* about what they've already written. I do not know why you keep insisting there is.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZIlAExvneo&t=6s. Take it up on https://english.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

That is because of the definition of the quantifier that it represent, in the case of `all` is the *for all* quantifier, by definition the quantifier should return the neutral element of the operator when apply to an empty set, the operator of the *for all* is the *and* operator and its neutral is *True* (True and X == X), same deal for `any` that is the quantifier *exist*, which operator is *or* and its neutral is False (False or X == X)

`all([])==True` is vacuously true that all element in this empty set of thing comply with whatever condition

`any([])==False` no element in this empty set of thing comply with whatever condition

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding a pseudo-code trying to explain that a "neutral" value (does not change the result) is the correct result for doing a mathematical operation (`all` from this question is a logical conjuction) on empty input:

- `0 + numX = numX`, that's why `sum(<empty>)` = `sum(0, <empty>)` = `sum(0)` = `0`
- `1 * numY = numY`, that's why `product(<empty>)` = `product(1, <empty>)` = `product(1)` = `1`
- `True and boolX = boolX`, that's why `all(<empty>)` = `all(True, <empty>)` = `all(True)` = `True`
- `False or boolY = boolY`, that's why `any(<empty>)` = `any(False, <empty>)` = `any(False)` = `False`

Answer (score -1):

```py
#This doesn't print anything
for p in set():
  print('p', p)

# This yields an empty list
print([n % p > 0 for p in primes])

# This returns true (primes = set())
print(all([n % p > 0 for p in primes]))

# This also returns true
print(all([n % p > 0 for p in []]))

# This returns false
print(any([n % p > 0 for p in []]))

print(all([True]), all([False]))

print(all([]))

print(all([True, True]), all([True, False]))
```

Output of the above code lines-

[image: Output]

So it's not about `all()` it's that `all()` returns `True` or `False` based on the argument passed, in your case `all([n % p > 0 for p in primes])` is an empty list hence it would return `True` and *if condition* is always `True`!.

Instead you can modify condition to check for the length `len([n % p > 0 for p in primes]) and all(n % p > 0 for p in primes)` to get correct response.